# Using set in a batch cmd file to update a variable value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, set, echo

Batch file `Test.cmd`:

```
@set args=args1
@set value=value1

@if defined value (
  @echo args: [%args%], value: [%value%]
  @set args=%args% /value=%value%
  @echo args: [%args%]
)

@echo args: [%args%]
```

Output of command `>.\Test.cmd`:

```
args: [args1], value: [value1]
args: [args1]
args: [args1 /value=value1]
```

Why do each of my calls to `@echo args: [%args%]` return different values? (One without the updated args value, `args1`, and one with the update, `args1 /value=value1`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, instead of using `@` at the beginning of each line, just put `@echo off` at the very start of your script which will do the same but save you having to put `@` on every line.

I would also suggest using `setlocal` at the begining of your scripts to avoid leavng variables defined on your system once the CMD window/script closes. It causes the variables to only be accessible for that CMD/script instance.

Try the following code and notice the `echo args: [!args!]`

```bat
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set args=args1
set value=value1

if defined value (
  echo args: [%args%], value: [%value%]
  set args=%args% /value=%value%
  echo args: [!args!]
)

echo args: [%args%]

endlocal
pause
```

Output:

```bat
args: [args1], value: [value1]
args: [args1 /value=value1]
args: [args1 /value=value1]
```

Read up more about the use of `EnableDelayedExpansion` here...https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html